# Calculating Social Welfare from an Energy Subsidy

Tags: microeconomics, energy-economics

In Allcott and Greenstone's paper, ["Is there an energy efficiency gap?"](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/jep.26.1.3), one finds the following figure[image]

I quote now from p. 13:

> "When there are investment inefficiencies, the original marginal
>   consumer at quantity *q* gains amount *af* from being induced to buy the
>   energy efficient good. In fact, there are allocative gains from
>   inducing each of the consumers between *q* and and *q′′* to purchase the energy efficient good, as each of these consumers has
>   benefits that are larger than incremental cost *c*. The total private
>   welfare gains are illustrated by the triangle *abf*...These benefits are then
>   compared against the costs of the policy. A subsidy involves a
>   transfer of public funds to consumers of amount *hbjk* , as illustrated
>   by the shaded rectangle."

My question is rather straightforward: why are the benefits of the subsidy given only by the triangle *abf*, and not by all of the area between the two lines *D* and *D'* above the incremental cost line *c*? Is it not in fact true that every consumer upto the point *j* on the line *D* sees a gain equal to vertical distance between his present position and *D'*?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are asking, "Why just $abf$ and not $abf + abj$?"

Comment: No, I mean _abf_ plus the quadrilateral with one side _af_ and then extending upwards to the left.